# How to check if a user-defined function is already registered in Julia/JuMP

Tags: julia, mathematical-optimization, julia-jump

I want to check if a user-defined function is already registered in JuMP/julia.  Here's an example:

```
function foo( f, f1, f2 )

  if !function_is_registered(:f)  # This is what I'm looking for
    JuMP.register(:f,1,f1,f2)
  end
  ####
    # Optimization problem here using f
    # Leads to some return statement
  ####
end

f(x) = exp( A * x )
f1(x) = A * exp( A * x )
f2(x) = A * A * exp( A * x )
    # Function to register

A = 2
use1 = foo(f, f1, f2)
use2 = foo(f, f1, f2)
    # This second usage would fail without the check.  Can't re-register f.
```

As should be obvious from the comments, the check is needed for the second usage.  As far as I can tell, JuMP registers functions at a global level - once registered they can't be re-defined locally (right? If they can, this solves my problem too!).

Comment: This isn't supported yet. Please [open an issue](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl/issues/new) with the feature request.

Comment: Thanks.  Issue 821 opened.  See here for future reference:  https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl/issues/821

Comment: @mlubin detecting registration is pretty straightforward using a simple try / catch block. Maybe it would be more useful to just provide a more general "deregistering" interface, similar to what I've done in my answer below

Comment: Unfortunately deregistering is inherently unsafe and can corrupt existing JuMP models, not something I want to make easy to do. The solution is to make registration local to a model, but that will take more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want.

```
using JuMP
using Ipopt
```

```
function set_A_sol( A )
  f = (x) -> exp( A * x ) - x
  f1 = (x) -> A * exp( A * x ) - 1.0
  f2 = (x) -> A * A * exp( A * x )
  # Local redefinition of f
  try
    JuMP.register(:f, 1, f, f1, f2)
  catch e
    if e.msg == "Operator f has already been defined"
      ind = pop!( ReverseDiffSparse.univariate_operator_to_id, :f);
      deleteat!( ReverseDiffSparse.univariate_operators, ind);
      pop!( ReverseDiffSparse.user_univariate_operator_f, ind);
      pop!( ReverseDiffSparse.user_univariate_operator_fprime, ind);
      pop!( ReverseDiffSparse.user_univariate_operator_fprimeprime, ind);
      JuMP.register(:f, 1, f, f1, f2);
    end
  end
  mod = Model(solver=Ipopt.IpoptSolver(print_level=0))
  @variable(mod, - Inf <= x <= Inf )
  @NLobjective(mod, Min, f(x) )
  status=solve(mod)
  return getvalue(x)
end
```

```
julia> ans1 = set_A_sol(0.5)
1.3862943611200509
```

```
julia> ans2 = set_A_sol(1.0)
0.0
```

```
julia> ans3 = set_A_sol(2.0)
-0.34657359027997264
```

Explanation:

If you look at the register function, defined in nlp.jl, "Registering" involves adding the symbol to a dictionary, held in ReverseDiffSparse.
Register a function and check those dictionaries manually to see what they look like.

So "*de-registering*" simply involves removing all traces of :f and its derivatives from all the places where it has been recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extended answer based on Tasos's suggestions (thanks Tasos!).

**tl;dr** You can use try-catch statement for something that is already registered.  You can also change parameters in the objective function in the global environment, but cannot wrap them in functions.

The following effectively permits checking for redefinition of a function:

```
function foo2( f, f1, f2 )
  try
    JuMP.register(:f,1,f1,f2)
  end
  ####
  # Optimization problem here using f
  # Leads to some return statement
  ####
  end
end
```

What's even better is that you can actually use the naive way that JuMP looks for `f` to change parameters in the objective function (although you need to redefine the model each time as you can't put a `@NLparameter` in a user-defined objective).  For example:

```
using JuMP
using Ipopt

f = (x) -> exp( A * x ) - x
f1 = (x) -> A * exp( A * x ) - 1.0
f2 = (x) -> A * A * exp( A * x )
    # Period objective function
JuMP.register(:f, 1, f, f1, f2)

A = 1.0
mod = Model(solver=Ipopt.IpoptSolver(print_level=0))
@variable(mod, - Inf <= x <= Inf )
@NLobjective(mod, Min, f(x) )
status=solve(mod)
println("x = ", getvalue(x))
  # Returns 0

A = 2.0
mod = Model(solver=Ipopt.IpoptSolver(print_level=0))
@variable(mod, - Inf <= x <= Inf )
@NLobjective(mod, Min, f(x) )
status=solve(mod)
println("x = ", getvalue(x))
  # Returns -0.34657 (correct)
```

You can even redefine `f` to something totally different and that will still work too.  However, you can't wrap this in a function.  For example:

```
function set_A_sol( A )
  f = (x) -> exp( A * x ) - x
  f1 = (x) -> A * exp( A * x ) - 1.0
  f2 = (x) -> A * A * exp( A * x )
      # Local redefinition of f
  try
    JuMP.register(:f, 1, f, f1, f2)
  end
  mod = Model(solver=Ipopt.IpoptSolver(print_level=0))
  @variable(mod, - Inf <= x <= Inf )
  @NLobjective(mod, Min, f(x) )
  status=solve(mod)
  return getvalue(x)
end

ans1 = set_A_sol(0.5)
ans2 = set_A_sol(1.0)
ans3 = set_A_sol(2.0)
  # All return 1.38629
```

I don't totally understand why, but it appears that the first time that `A` is set inside `set_A_sol`, the JuMP registration fixes `A` once and for all.  Given this is the thing that I ultimately want to be able to do, I'm still stuck.  Suggestions welcome!